# Barriers and ETH, or its variants

Tags: fine-grained, barriers, p-hardness

**ETH** (Exponential Time Hypothesis) or its variants **SETH**(Strong ETH), **NSETH**(Non Deterministic SETH) haven't been resolved as yet. But resolution to any of the above hypotheses could lead to interesting relationships, possibly easily verifiable certificates, and circuit complexity results that could lead to better algorithm design. What kind of barrier relationships/results are we looking at when reasoning about **ETH**(or its variants), and results  that can shed light on problems such as **3SUM**, **OV**(Orthogonal Vectors), or others?

Comment: Are you asking about barriers to proving ETH, refuting ETH, ...? The barriers to proving ETH (if it is true) are at least as high as the barriers to proving P != NP. The barrier to refuting ETH (if it is false) is our lack of algorithmic creativity...